# what is the safe way to pass pointers to structs between C and Java in JNI programming?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have wrapped the libusb in a JNI wrapper (with some other stuff). I need to be able to pass the usb_device between Java and C.

In my java class I have a long field which gets set by the constructor which is called from C. In the C code I cast the pointer to the usb struct like this

```
device = (*env)->NewObject(env, class, mid, (jlong)list->dev);
```

Later in another C function implementing a method, I retrieve the pointer

```
jlong device_pointer;
device_pointer = (*env)->GetLongField(env, device, fid);
```

This seems to work ok on linux, but something gets screwed up in the mac. This doesn't seem to be a safe way to pass pointers between C and Java. What is the safe way to do this?

Comment: Passing pointers like that works fine in [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/), even on Mac OS X.